# How To Connect Sql Server Management Studio v18.5 to localhost

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to connect SSMS 18.5 to a localhost connection so I can play around with toy data to learn some things.  I regularly use it to connect to external databases, but I am having a hard time getting it to work locally.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**ATTEMPT 1:**

I started by looking at the official documentation from Microsoft on getting this setup from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-connecting-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

My problem with this is that when I went to `Database Engine --> Local Server Groups --> Tasks --> Register Local Servers` I was always greeted with this error message:

[image]

I tried reinstalling my program to see if there was a problem with my configuration but that didn't work either.

Then I tried using the `Connect Object Explorer` and signing on using Windows authentication like so:

[image]

But that returned this message:

[image]

If I want to get a local connection, what do I do?

Comment: If SQL Server is running on the local host, then use `.` as the hostname. If the instance has a name, then `./{Instance Name}` (for example `./SQLEXPRESS`).

Comment: Do you know if there is a local SQL instance running on your machine? Check the services (Start menu > search 'services') and scroll down to 'SQL Server'. If such a line does not exist, then there is no SQL engine installed locally. If the line exists, then it will tell you the instance name between parentheses. Secondly, make sure the service is actually running (if not use the Start button).